# JToggleButton and unexpected nullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, nullpointerexception, jtogglebutton

I have a class `PolaczZBaza` with 2 methods-
`polacz()` - to open a connection with sql database
`rozlacz()` to close this database
there is a `JToggleButton` which is used for connecting with this database.

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        try {
            PolaczZBaza.polacz();
            this.setText("Rozłącz z bazą danych");
            MenuGorne.ustawienia.setEnabled(false);
            PanelGlowny.ustawienia.setEnabled(false);
            PanelGlowny.wykonaj.setEnabled(true);
            PanelGlowny.importXML.setEnabled(true);
            MenuGorne.importXML.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Błąd łączenia z bazą danych2");
        }
    } else {
        try {
            PolaczZBaza.rozlacz();
            this.setText("Połącz z bazą danych");
            MenuGorne.ustawienia.setEnabled(true);
            PanelGlowny.ustawienia.setEnabled(true);
            PanelGlowny.wykonaj.setEnabled(false);
            PanelGlowny.importXML.setEnabled(false);
            MenuGorne.importXML.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Błąd podczas próby rozłączenia z bazą danych");
        }
    }
}
```

when the connection can not be established there are an message but at the same time method `rozlacz()` throws `NullPointerException`. I think it's because he is trying to close unopened 
connection, but I do not know why this is happening because method `rozlacz()` shouldn't be made

```
public static void rozlacz() throws SQLException {
    statement.close();

}
```

thanks for help
EDIT:
        public class PolaczZBaza {

```
public static Connection connection;
public static Statement statement;

public static void polacz() throws SQLException {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql://"
            + PanelGlowny.ustawieniaBazy.getSerwer() + "/"
            + PanelGlowny.ustawieniaBazy.getSciezka() + "\"",
            PanelGlowny.ustawieniaBazy.getLogin(),
            PanelGlowny.ustawieniaBazy.getHaslo());
    statement = connection.createStatement();
}

public static void rozlacz() throws SQLException {
    statement.close();

}
```

PanelGlowny.ustawieniaBazy it's a frame with settings. If i type a correct data everything it's fine

Comment: Can you also add the code in the `polacz()` method please?

Comment: i edited, sorry for the Polish names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post full PolaczZBaza class. Anyway, statement may be null. In this case, we are creating this construction:

```
void closeResources(PreparedStatement statement, ResultSet resultSet, Connection connection) {
    if(statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException) { //log..}
    if(resultSet!= null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException) { //log..}
    if(connection!= null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException) { //log..}
}
```

it is null pointer safe and catching exception makes sure that all resources will be closed anyway.

Comment: can u explain to me why when i click button it throws an exception and method PolaczZBaza.rozlacz() in the else block will perform

Comment: I would change your itemStateChanged method: First, check if e is instance of your JToggleButton. Then, cast e to ToggleButton: `JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();`. And finally, instead of checking `if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) ... else ...`, check `if (button.isSelected()) ... else ...`

Comment: thanks for help, i added if (PolaczZBaza.statement != null) before closing and it helps